# Transferring NFT Tokens without the ownership

Tags: solidity, contract-development, dapps, erc-721, nft

I'm wondering how opensea transferring tokens to the buyer without having the ownership of that token.And also they are not using escrow account at all.In remix, If i tried to transfer the token without the ownershipp , It's not working and giving error "ERC721: transfer caller is not owner nor approved". How can i do this action like opensea..

Comment: I have not read the source code of OpenSea, but my assumption is that the owner approves OpenSea smart contract to transfer any particular token on behalf of them.

Comment: https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/opensea-creatures/blob/master/contracts/ERC721Tradable.sol

Answer (score 2):

OpenSea has a contract [ERC721Tradable.sol](https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/opensea-creatures/blob/master/contracts/ERC721Tradable.sol) that whitelist the OpenSea operator

```
    /**
     * Override isApprovedForAll to whitelist user's OpenSea proxy accounts to enable gas-less listings.
     */
    function isApprovedForAll(address owner, address operator)
        override
        public
        view
        returns (bool)
    {
        // Whitelist OpenSea proxy contract for easy trading.
        ProxyRegistry proxyRegistry = ProxyRegistry(proxyRegistryAddress);
        if (address(proxyRegistry.proxies(owner)) == operator) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.isApprovedForAll(owner, operator);
    }
```

Comment: Okay I have Aproved the certain accounts while transferring the token. Which address i have to use as a from address,while transferring tokens. If i use the aproved address, It showing error like "Transferring of token that not owned". Also if i want to use owner address i have to be the owner while transferring tokens.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. Are you developing your own contract? or you are using opensea contracts?

Comment: Yeah I'm developing contracts using openzeppelin library for ERC721

Comment: @MAHENDRANKANAGARAJ without the code is hard to say, usually `from` is the token's owner and msg.sender is the operator. But those are names that are easy to change in the code.

Comment: I saw the opensea contracts. Can you please explain the function in  line 91        https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/opensea-creatures/blob/master/contracts/ERC721Tradable.sol

Comment: @MAHENDRANKANAGARAJ If you have a new question it is better to ask it by clicking on [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. You can add a link to this question if it helps setting the context.

Answer (score 1):

You can transfer the token without the ownership. If you give an address approval, the address can transfer the token.

```
function approve(address _approved, uint256 _tokenId)
```

This function is used to give an address approval. In the transfer function of ERC-721. The `from` address must be either the token owner or have an approval.

Here is the transfer function

```
function transferFrom(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 tokenId
    ) public virtual override {
        //solhint-disable-next-line max-line-length
        require(_isApprovedOrOwner(_msgSender(), tokenId), "ERC721: transfer caller is not owner nor approved");

        _transfer(from, to, tokenId);
    }
```

Comment: I have used the contract address as approved address from the owner. Then i tried to transfer the tokens, But it showing error like "Your balance should be higher than you send"